# i am not able to render my urls in my template it gives me error rendering

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-url-reverse

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'Jersey' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Jersey/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Below is the code to my `views.py`

```
class JerseyView(TemplateView):
        #paginate_by=3
     template_name='Ecommerce/Jersey.html'
    
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):    
         et =super(JerseyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         et['United']= Item.objects.filter(category="3").filter(subcategory="9")
         et['Chelsea']= Item.objects.filter(category="3").filter(subcategory="10")
         return et
```

below is the code for my `urls.py`

```
path('Jersey/<slug>/', JerseyView.as_view(), name="Jersey" ),
```

I called This link in my Navbar as

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'Ecommerce:Jersey' %}">Men's Clothing</a>
```

when I click on it it gives me the error as NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'Jersey' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Jersey/(?P[^/]+)/$']
I don't know if there's something i am missing out because i have checked my spelling and still getting the same error

Comment: you have to specify slug for href tag in Navbar

Comment: I just made it {% url 'Ecommerce:Jersey' Jersey.slug %} buh still gives the error of NoReverse match found

Answer (score 0):

By using `{% url 'Ecommerce:Jersey' %}`, you're trying to access `Jersey/<slug>` path without giving any argument. So Django router expect a argument on this path (slug).

You need to provide it, (only you knows what slug goes there...) like this :

`{% url 'Ecommerce:Jersey' Jersey.slug %}`

Comment: Still reading same error Reverse for Jersey with arguments not found @BriseBalloches

Comment: How do you refer to a Jersey object in your template ? You need to change Jersey.slug to <reference-of-Jersey>.slug so it can work. @proflord

Comment: What do u mean by <reference of Jersey>.slug pls. I dnt get it

Comment: In your template, how do you get the Jersey slug from your context ? (Something like United.id ?) @proflord

Comment: In my template I use {% url 'Ecommerce:Jersey' Jersey.slug %} to get it in my homepage

Comment: In ```'Jersey/<slug>/'``` what do you expect in place of <slug> ? @proflord

Answer (score 0):

is this slug dynamically change or not? if it is then first you should correct your url like this:  `'Jersey/<slug:slug>/'` and in href tag, get slug from context you passed in views.py like what user BriseBalloches said. but if your slug is a fixed parameter, you can just write it in href tag. suppose your slug parameter is `country` then your href tag should work with `href="Jersey/country"` or `href="{% url 'Ecommerce:Jersey'country %}"`

these href tags will generate `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Jersey/country`

Comment: The slug dynamically changes I just added the Jersey/slug:slug into my urls how should it be rendered in the template? Something like app_name:Jersey Jersey.slug?

Comment: aren't you using link in navbar? then why and how it should change dynamically . can you share your any desk address??